# OSX making NSCollectionView in Xcode 6.4 with objective c

Tags: macos, view, collections, xcode6

I have looked up a lot of resources for programming  NSCollectionView  but couldn't find any please help.

Seen following but not working:

1.https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html
2. not found any relevant source code on github
3.watched-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw-sHMTsMVs but outdated.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You mention Xcode 6.4. Is that for a specific reason?

If you have the opportunity to upgrade then Apple has introduced a new NSCollectionView in OSX 10.11 El Capitan.

You can watch the WWDC introduction video [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-225/)

The related example can be downloaded from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/CocoaSlideCollection) in ObjectiveC

And if you'd like an example in Swift, the [Exhibition](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/Exhibition/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016178-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) example is worth investigating.

All of the above is 10.11 only, so if you're stuck on Xcode 6.4 then the above won't be of any usage to you, sorry

Comment: Sorry, i can't upgrade to 10.11  , I  am using 10.10 and coding with Objective C.